# QGIS atlas, add picture with path from attribute

Tags: qgis, atlas, expression

I love working with the atlas generator and I came up with a new case to use it for. I want to add a picture to my map from URL.
I am allowed to add a picture if I type in the full url path. eg. http://my.url.service.no/pics/img_001.jpg
But I want to add the picture based on the filename from my table.
See example in my print screen.

Using the same expression creating a lable it give me the string for the complete url eg. `http://my.url.service/[%"filename"%]` evaluates to  `http://my.url.service/img_001.jpg`

Is it possible to do what I try here, anyone with experience or tips?

[image: print screen]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with `concat('http://www.example.com/img/',"filename",'.jpg')`, replace the .jpg with the appropriate extension if all of your images are the same type.

Or `concat('http://www.sylve.ch/docs/',"filename")` if the extension .jpg or else is included in your name's file.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it at last using
'http://www.example.com/img/'||"filename"

However romainbh answer also work!
Thanks romainbh

Comment: I´m having trouble doing this. Question: Hows the path written in the table? And then you "call" the picture by labeling in Composer, right?

Comment: The path is not fully written in the table, it's just the filename that is stored in the table eg img5146.jpg. The path to the file is static and is written in the expression. The filename is appended to the path by using ||.  The path can also be a place on you local disk. I hope that make sense, iam typing from my phone.

Comment: Nahh I lost it, but a freind showed me another method. That method is with the full path in table and using the "add picture" in composer. But thanks.